# Running Linux for development: pros and cons of VM vs docker desktop?

Tags: virtual-machine, distribution-choice

My main workmachines these days are an iMac and a Macbook, because I work as a mobile app dev and for building iOS apps, you need a Mac system.

That said, for the sake of fun and knowledge, I want to re-learn OS kernel dev. I've found some repos that are easily buildable on Linux (still have a PC running Debian ready). These repos require some tools that are unfortunately Linux only, so I'd like to install Linux "inside" my Mac. At the moment, not interested in dual-boot.

Now I've installed Debian on VirtualBox, and so far it works OK. I wonder, though, if there's a less resource approach for running Linux: perhaps docker? What are the pros and cons? My understanding so far is docker is suited for reproducibility, to avoid the classic "this setup works OK on my machine but not sure why it crashes on yours". Not sure if it fits my case.

Answer (score 3):

To run a  Linux kernel docker or podman, the system puts up a VM; you're hence asking for whether "VM or VM?".

So, either way you get Linux in a VM; the ways you interact with that are different. Since the setup effort for someone used to mobile dev environments would be described as "minimal", I don't think it makes sense to advise based on our subjective impressions without knowing what *you* need.

Chances are that with a classical hypervisor it's easier to just swap out the kernel, so you might want to run a VM to test your kernel, and a docker/`podman machine` VM'ed container for the Linux development.

By the way, Linux kernel development *is* quite portable, you should *not* actually need a VM to build a linux kernel!

Comment: I should be more specific, then. I'm not learning Linux kernel development, but some smaller kernels (including Xv6). There's one or two projects which require FASM assembler, which easily run on Windows/Linux/DOS/BSD, but not on Mac... yet. At the moment, I just want to build and run and compile the code, and not messing with the toolchain itself. My requirement is pretty common, something like GCC + NASM/FASM + mkisofs/genisoimage + xorriso + git. I've created a Debian VM for that purpose. And I just learn that Docker by default don't store your data persistently....

Comment: Docker is Linux based, it won’t create an Xv6 container. The idea of Docker is to have a schizophrenic Linux kernel and multiple environments on top of it.